# Get value from select event of ajax and pass it to jsp form

Tags: ajax, jsp

```
select: function(event, ui) {
      spinstring = ui.item.label;
}
```

This is my ajax select event. I need to send the `spinstring` value to jsp form in same jsp page.
How to send this?

Comment: Do you want to set the value to the form:input element ? please expain it clearly

Comment: yeah. I have an input element in jsp page. I need to set this input element by spinstring-- from ajax

Comment: What does not  work?

Comment: I don't know the logic or syntax.

Comment: Thanks Ravi Thapliyal. Your answer is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say, you have an `<input>` field with `id` *spin*

```
<input type="text" id="spin" />
```

Then you can set its value using jQuery as

```
select: function(event, ui) {
  spinstring = ui.item.label;
  $( #spin ).val( spinstring );
}
```

In pure Javascript you would need to use the `document` object.

```
document.getElementById("spin").value = ui.item.label;
```